# Removing anchors with specific text or urls

Tags: php

Example:

```
<?php
$content ='<a href="">REMOVE ME</a>
<a href="">KEEP ME</a>
<a href="">REMOVE PLEASE</a>
<a href="">KEEP remove</a>';
?>
```

I like to remove all anchors with keyword remove. is this possible in php?

Comment: Easiest would be to use jquery. It's quite easy with that.

Comment: yes it is possible in php as well as in javascript.

Comment: A few years ago I tried the DOMDocument: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php it worked as expected. Just load the html content and manipulate the DOM tree.

Comment: @JonStirling: ahan, u r right, just read this remove all anchors :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also consider `DOMDocument` as most preferable solution for such cases. But as an alternative way here is quick solution with `preg_replace` (just for your case):

```
$cleared_content = preg_replace("/<a href=[\"\"|'']+>.*?remove.*?<\/a>/iu","",$content);
```

Comment: Thanks, fastest way to do it imho.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to remove all the links which have 'remove' keyword in the text then you can do as :

```
$content ='<a href="">REMOVE ME</a>
           <a href="">KEEP ME</a>
           <a href="">REMOVE PLEASE</a>
           <a href="">KEEP remove</a>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($content);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node) {
   if(stripos($node->textContent,'remove') === false)
        echo $dom->saveHtml($node), PHP_EOL;
}
```

And if you need to remove all the links which have 'remove' keyword in `href` also then use below `foreach` loop

```
$content ='<a href="google.com">REMOVE ME</a>
           <a href="yahoo.com">KEEP ME</a>
           <a href="gmail.com">REMOVE PLEASE</a>
           <a href="test.com">KEEP remove</a>
           <a href="remove.com">KEEPKEEP</a>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($content);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node) {
    $node_href='';
    if($node->hasAttribute( 'href' ))
        $node_href = $node->getAttribute( 'href' );
    if(stripos($node->textContent,'remove') === false && stripos($node_href,'remove') === false)
        echo $dom->saveHtml($node), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$content = preg_replace(array('"<a href(.*?)>"', '"</a>"'), array('',''), $content);
```